# Css Positioning Problem

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, positioning

I am implementing the Filament Group jquery  menu ( http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/ ). If you have a look at the screen grab I have linked to below you will see that the menu is pushing itself outside of its container div. Can somebody please give me some clues as to how i can force the menu to stay inside its parent div?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a simple margin-problem to me. Have you tried taking the margin away?

Comment: it would be good if you could post your html/css for this so we can see the structure of things

Comment: without the source code we can not assist you in your troubles

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the menu has been floated or removed from the document flow with `position: absolute`.

If it has been floated then you can either float the parent too or use this css on the parent:

W3C:-

```
#parentElement:after {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
     content: ".";
     height: 0;
     visibility: hidden;
    }
```

IE7:-

```
#parentElement {
 min-height: 0;
}
```

If the menu is not floated but uses `position: absolute` then you either have to set the height manually or use JS to measure the height of the menu and apply it to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at that screenshot its near impossible to know without seeing your css and mark up,  however it looks like your left values are a wrong for the pop out menu. But thats a guess without seeing the code...

Looking at the example page it uses negative left which is equal to the width of the UL to switch them, so without reading the implementation of that plugin you might need to set that width somewhere or your missing something...